# openCV Android: knnMatcher returns only matches for 1 descriptor

Tags: android, opencv, sift, surf, knn

I have to implement a logo detection algoritm for android for my masterthesis.
I'm currently using the openCV android library with NDK and have already managed to detect keypoints and setup descriptors for these keypoints using SURF.

Next step for me is to find 2 nearest matches for every keypoint using **knnMatch**, afterwards i'm throwing away the matches where the best knn match isn't very distinguishable compared with the second (the distance ration of these two is too low)
here's a part of my code:

```
private static List<DMatch> knn(Mat queryDescriptors, Mat trainDescriptors) {
    List<List<DMatch>> matches = new ArrayList<List<DMatch>>();
    List<DMatch> retMatches = new ArrayList<DMatch>();
    DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher
            .create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE);
    matcher.knnMatch(queryDescriptors, trainDescriptors, matches, 2);
```

My problem here is that when I have for example 500 descriptors for the query logo and 400 for the train logo, knn returns 500 matches, but **every single one** is for one and the same keypoint. Normally, it returns the 2 best matches for every descriptor, so 500 different descriptors, now they return 500 times the best matches for one and the same descriptor.

**So when i draw these knn matches, there is 1 match line, drawn 500 times, between always the same keypoints**

When I try the simple matcher, who simply returns the best match, I get more lines.
I've tested this with comparing an image to itself. Knn return this one line, where a simple match draws all 500 matches, who are in this case ofcourse correct.

I can't find any posts where this similar issue has been treated, does any one had this problem or knows what i'm doing wrong here?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next time you face a bug in OpenCV, please check if it's already submitted at [OpenCV bug tracker](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/issues) and submit a new one if not found.
What you faced is a bug in the JNI wrapper to C++ matcher, the fix has been just commited to OpenCV trunk.
But you can make it locally in your copy of OpenCV-2.3.1, this is just one line of code:

1. open org.opencv.utils.Converters::Mat_to_vector_vector_DMatch(Mat m, List> lldm) in OpenCV-2.3.1 Android library project (Converters.java)
2. move the line `List<DMatch> ldm = new ArrayList<DMatch>();` two lines down to make it the 1st line of the cycle `for (Mat mi : mats)`
3. rebuild the OpenCV-2.3.1 project and your own in Eclipse
4. make sure that now the matcher returns correct results

Comment: thanks! this worked, I'm still not finding the right matches but knnMatches' behaviour is normal now.

I've never found the openCV bug tracker while searching for this problem (google,..) but now I'll definitely check this when a problem occurs!

thanks!